# Issue downloading MobileNet weights

Tags: python-3.x, macos, keras, pip, mobilenet

When I run this code:

```
base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False)  # imports the mobilenet model and discards the last 1000 neuron layer.
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)  # we add dense layers so that the model can learn more complex functions and classify for better results.
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)  # dense layer 2
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)  # dense layer 3
preds = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(x)  # final layer with softmax activation
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)
```

This is the error I get:

```
    Exception: URL fetch failure on https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.6/mobilenet_1_0_224_tf_no_top.h5 : None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
```

In order to overcome this, I ran the Certificates.command in the Python 3.7 folder. However, when I do so, I get this error:

```
Last login: Wed Feb  5 12:38:14 on ttys001
/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;
ruvenguna~$ /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Collecting certifi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/df50cac98ea0d5b006c55a399c3bf1db9da7b5a24de7890bc9cfd5dd9e99/certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Even though the process is completed, I still get the same error I did initially. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the below lines before downloading the MobileNet model weights worked for me:

```
import ssl    
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Hope this helps! :)